# Constrain a responsive square inside a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### tl;dr

How can I create an inner square that fills a flex item as much as it can while maintaining a 1/1 aspect ratio and not forcing the flex item to expand beyond its allocated size?

### Goal

I'm trying to create a layout with a flexbox header and footer each taking their auto-calculated height and a content area filling the rest and the entire flexbox exactly fills the body without causing any scroll or overflow. Inside the content area I need a square div that is 100% of the width ***OR*** 100% of the height, *whichever is smaller*.

[image: Desired and actual results]

### Problem

The problem I'm running into is if I base the size of the box on the width and the viewport is wider than it is tall, then the square forces the flex item it's in to expand and the entire flexbox/body/html to expand beyond the `100vh` it's explicitly set to. The same is true if the square size is based on the height--it works if the viewport is wider than it is tall but not otherwise.

### Question

How can I create an inner square that fills the flex item as much as it can while maintaining a 1/1 aspect ratio and not forcing the flex item to expand beyond its allocated size?

### What I've tried

Here's the code I have along with several variations I've tried.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">Header</div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="should-be-constrained-square"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .header {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .content {
    flex: 1 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  .footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .should-be-constrained-square {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background-color: red;

    /*
        Also tried:
        https://tylerduprey-52451.medium.com/a-perfect-square-with-css-964499440998

        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-top: 100%;
    */

    /*
        And tried:
        https://dev.to/tchaflich/a-width-responsive-perfect-square-in-pure-css-3dao

        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        position: relative;
    */

    /*
        And tried:
        https://www.sodawebmedia.com/insights/create-responsive-square-css/

        width: 100%;

        .should-be-constrained-square:after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
          padding-top: 100%;
        }
    */
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using the `vmin`/`vmax` units?

Comment: @psdpainter, no, of course I didn't think about using those. I'd never heard of them before.  So that led to a nice jaunt around MDN. `vmin`/`vmax` had the same problem of the box not actually being constrained. But there are so many more units in CSS than I knew about that I guess came about since I switched to Android dev for a few years. **WOW** so many cool things. Query Containers were the trick that worked. I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found a crazy simple solution using the newly introduced CSS unit [`qcmin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#cqmin). Credit goes to [@psdpainter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026660/psdpainter). Their comment about using `vmin` and `vmax` led me to research [all the many new CSS units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) which landed me on [Container Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) and [`qcmin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#cqmin).

[image: Desired behavior achieved with cqmin]

By setting the parent's [`container-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type) property and then setting both the child (square) element's `width` and `height` properties to [`qcmin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#cqmin). That's all it took.

Interestingly this is using the Container Query functionality but there is no actual container query involved. It's only taking advantage of some of what was introduced to support container queries.

Fully working code.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">Header</div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>

<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .header {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .content {
    flex: 1 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    container-type: size;
  }

  .footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .square {
    width: 100cqmin;
    height: 100cqmin;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very clean!  Love this <3

Answer (score 1):

## The issue is that you need a relationship from the child's width, to the parents height.

### A few Key Points

- `clamp(300px, 100%, var(--parent-height))`
- `position: absolute;` & `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1`
- `ResizeObserver`

##### In this example below

*(Note it doesn't work in StackOverFlows demo because I'm using `lvh`)*

I'm setting the `.box`'s width to `clamp(300px, 100%, var(--parent-height))` which will ensure the `.box`'s width is:

- Min `300px`
- Max: `var(--parent-height)`
- Native: `100%`

This allows the `.box` to take up 100% of the width on Mobile, and devices that have more vertical room than horizontal room. Although, the `.box` will NEVER be wider then the parents height.

#### `[position: absolute][2];` & `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1`

What this does, it allows the `#parent` to grow to the full width, without consideration for the height of the child box. The `aspect-ratio` ensures that the `.box` will always be a perfect square relative to it's width or height.

#### Finally `ResizeObserver`

The `ResizeObserver` allows us to feed additional information into CSS, and all the `clamp()` to actually work by referencing the height of the parent.

Unless you know the height's of the Header & Footer, there's no way to get this relationship solely in CSS. If you did know the heights, then you could run a CSS `calc(100lvh - <HEADER_HEIGHT> - <FOOTER_HEIGHT>)` to set the `max-width` of the child box.

```js
onload = () => {
  // Helper function
  const watchResize = (element, callback) => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      for (let entry of entries) {
        console.log(`entry.contentRect.height:`, entry.contentRect.height);
        element.style.setProperty('--parent-height', `${entry.contentRect.height}px`);
      }
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(element);
  };

  // Init
  const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
  watchResize(parent);
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100lvh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header,
footer {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  --parent-height: 100lvh;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  width: clamp(300px, 100%, var(--parent-height));
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
  </header>
  <main id="parent">
    <div class="box">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vestibulum nulla ut nibh vulputate egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Very cool solution. I almost used it. @psdpainter's comment about `vmin` led me to stumble on another CSS unit `qcmin` which worked perfectly with only a single additional line of CSS on the parent. Container Queries are so cool and seem like they'll solve so many of the more complex things people have been trying to do with CSS for two decades.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for your use case!   One thing to caution is that container query's don't have wide support cross browsers yet, `qmin` is at about 85% support right now.   If you're okay with that support there's nothing wrong with it :) I personally try to target the last 3 major versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: thanks for the support note. I'm much less concerned than I used to be since auto-update of browsers is so prevalent now even within locked down corporate environments. All of our customers are at large financial institutions.